# How to compute $\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\,\frac{3n^{2}}{ 2n^{4} - 1}\,\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, trigonometric-series

I find this problem on facebook group.

$$\mbox{Is it possible to find exact value of}\quad
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\,\frac{3n^{2}}{ 2n^{4} - 1}\,\right)\ {\large ?}.
$$

I think this is not telescope sum. And Wolfram Alpha can not find it.
Thank in advances.

Comment: i have found this here $2.210139941827429199377208652709109873851358684445594495900981921214067964592584215472507914834046930$ but a closed formula must not exist

Comment: @Integrator had posted a hint here that implies that it can be rewritten as $\sum_n (\pi/2-\arctan\,n^2) + \sum_n (\pi/2-\arctan\,2n^2)$. Note sure why he erased it, it seems to hold up numerically.

Comment: [also relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308377/does-the-series-sum-limits-n-0-infty-left-frac-pi2-arctann-ri)

Answer (score 14):

Since:
$$\arctan\frac{3n^2}{2n^4-1}=\arctan\frac{1}{n^2}+\arctan\frac{1}{2n^2}$$
then:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\arctan\frac{3n^2}{2n^4-1} = \arg\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{i}{n^2}\right)+\arg\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{i}{2n^2}\right).\tag{1} $$
Since, by the Weierstrass product for the $\sinh$ function,
$$\frac{\sinh(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right),$$
and by telescopic property we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\arctan\frac{1}{2n^2}=\frac{\pi}{4},$$
it happens that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\arctan\frac{3n^2}{2n^4-1} &=& \frac{\pi}{4}+\arg\frac{\sinh(\pi e^{i\pi/4})}{\pi e^{i\pi/4}}=\arg\sinh\left(\pi e^{i\pi/4}\right)\\&=&\arg\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)\right)\\&=&\color{red}{\pi+\arctan\left(\tan\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\coth\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 3):

@Jack DAurizio answer is nice,and I have two solution  for this
\begin{align*}\arctan{\dfrac{1}{2n^2}}&=\arctan{\dfrac{2}{4n^2-1+1}}=\arctan{\dfrac{(2n+1)-(2n-1)}{1+(2n+1)(2n-1)}}\\
&=\arctan{(2n+1)}-\arctan{(2n-1)}
\end{align*}

solution 2:
\begin{align*}\arctan{\dfrac{1}{2n^2}}&=\arctan{\dfrac{n^2-(n^2-1)}{(n^2-n)+(n^2+n)}=\arctan{\dfrac{\dfrac{n}{n-1}-\dfrac{n+1}{n}}{1+\dfrac{n}{n-1}\cdot\dfrac{n+1}{n}}}}\\
&=\arctan{\dfrac{n}{n-1}}-\arctan{\dfrac{n+1}{n}}
\end{align*}

and for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan{\dfrac{1}{n^2}}=\arctan{\dfrac{\tan{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}-\tanh{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}}{\tan{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}+\tanh{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}}}$$
see this (AMM E3375) post: [prove this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan{\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}\right)}=\arctan{\left(\tan\left(\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}}\right)\cdots\right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613670/prove-this-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-left-dfrac1n21-right-arctan-l?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\pars{3n^{2} \over 2n^{4} - 1}}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\bracks{
\arctan\pars{1 \over n^{2}} + \arctan\pars{1 \over 2n^{2}}}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{2}
\dsc{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\pars{1 \over kn^{2}}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\dsc{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\pars{1 \over kn^{2}}}
> =\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{kn^{2} \over x^{2} + k^{2}n^{4}}\,\dd x
> ={1 \over k}\Re\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2} + x\ic/k}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over k}\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
> {1 \over \pars{n + 1 + \root{x\ic/k}}\pars{n + 1 - \root{x\ic/k}}}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over k}\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}
> {\Psi\pars{1 + \root{x\ic/k}} - \Psi\pars{1 - \root{x\ic/k}} \over 2\root{x\ic/k}}\,\dd x
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the Digamma Function.

With the change $\ds{\root{{x \over k}\,\ic}=t\ \imp\ x=-kt^{2}\,\ic}$:
\begin{align}&\dsc{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\pars{1 \over kn^{2}}}
={1 \over k}\,\Re\int_{0}^{\root{\ic/k}}
{\Psi\pars{1 + t} - \Psi\pars{1 - t} \over 2t}\,\pars{-2kt\,\ic\,\dd t}
\\[5mm]&=\Im\int_{0}^{\root{\ic/k}}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 + t} - \Psi\pars{1 - t}}\,\dd t
=\Im\int_{0}^{\root{\ic/k}}
\braces{{1 \over t} - \bracks{\Psi\pars{1 - t} - \Psi\pars{t}}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\Im\int_{0}^{\root{\ic/k}}
\bracks{{1 \over t} - \pi\cot\pars{\pi t}}\,\dd t
=\Im\bracks{
\ln\pars{\root{\ic \over k}} - \ln\pars{\sin\pars{\pi\root{\ic \over k}}}}
\end{align}

> However
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\Im\ln\pars{\root{\ic \over k}}}=\Im\ln\pars{1 + \ic \over \root{2k}}
> =\color{#00f}{{\pi \over 4}}
> \\[1cm]
> &\color{#00f}{\Im\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\pi\root{\ic \over k}}}}
> =\Im\ln\pars{\sin\pars{{\pi \over \root{2k}} + {\pi \over \root{2k}}\ic}}
> \\[5mm]&=\Im\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}\cosh\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}
> +\cos\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}\sinh\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#00f}{
> \arctan\pars{\cot\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}\tanh\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}}}
> \end{align}
>   such that
>   $$
> \dsc{\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\pars{1 \over kn^{2}}}\
> {\large =}\ \dsc{{\pi \over 4}
> -\arctan\pars{\cot\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}\tanh\pars{\pi \over \root{2k}}}}
> $$

With expression $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\arctan\pars{3n^{2} \over 2n^{4} - 1}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2}
-\arctan\pars{\cot\pars{\pi \over \root{2}}\tanh\pars{\pi \over \root{2}}}}
\\[5mm]&\approx{\tt 2.21013994}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $$\tan x=\frac{1}{n^2} \text{and } \tan y=\frac{1}{2n^2}$$  so we have that $$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}=\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2n^2}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)}=\frac{3n^2}{2n^4-1}$$ hence we have $$x+y=\arctan\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2n^2}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)}=\arctan\frac{1}{n^2}+\arctan\frac{1}{2n^2}.$$ From here I think you can do